# jQuery date picker : limit to selected month

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

how do i limit date range to selected month.
if user select month of November in 'From date' i need to limit 'To date' in that selected month. No matter user select November 30th. to date should only show November dates only. he cannot go beyond that month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2s8XL/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var maxDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, -0);
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

---

Another way

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2s8XL/1)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        stepMonths: 0,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What if i select 31-Dec-2015 in From Date selection?

Comment: @KuashalKhamar the user will be restricted to that date only . As it's last date of month so both to and from will be 31st Dec 2015 .